# Can't find Wordpress Footer image url

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been teaching myself Wordpress theme development and have a custom made theme on my website(made by another dev a while ago). I want to be able to download the footer background image but I can't seem to find the correct url for it. In the Style.css file the footer background image is declared as

```
background: url(images/layout/bg-footer-boards.jpg)
```

But mysite.com/images/layout/bg-footer-boards.jpg, mysite.com/wp-content/images/layout/bg-footer-boards.jpg, and mysite.com/themes/mytheme/wp-content/images/layout/bg-footer-boards.jpg all give me 404's. I think this is just something with the file path that I'm missing but any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css url() is relative to the file rather than the webroot.

So `images/layout/bg-footer-boards.jpg`

refers to a folder called `images/` located in the same folder as your .css file.